# What data type should I use to store an image with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an image with base64, e.g.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9w....
```

How to save in the database? What should be the type of the field in schema? Buffer?

Comment: Well it's a "string" whilst it's base64, but if you convert it then you can actually store as Binary. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to store images in the database, which is better? to store as string or to convert to binary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript Binary. Base64 encoding makes it "bigger". You only use it because you are restricted to sending "strings". So `Binary`. There is a MongoDB BSON Type and Schema Type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The short answer is store as ["Binary"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/), for which in a mongoose schema you can use `Buffer` to do this.

The longer form is to demonstrate a *round trip* of conversion starting with the original binary and back again. Base64 encoding/decoding is not a *necessary* step in most real world cases, and is just there for demonstration:

- Read an image (or any binary data) from file
- Base64 encode that data *(just to show it can be done) - optional*
- Turn back into Binary data from Base64 *( just to show it can be done ) - optional*
- Store Binary data in the database
- Read Binary data from the database
- Output binary data to a new file

So the Schema Part is simple, just use `Buffer`:

```
var albumSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: Buffer
})
```

Then all we are going to do is follow the process and put the binary data into the property and read it back out again.

Note though that if you are coming directly from a string with a MIME type on it like :

```
  data:image/png;base64,long-String
```

Just use a JavaScript `.split()` and take the second array index for the base64 string itself:

```
var string = "data:image/png;base64,long-String"
var bindata = new Buffer(string.split(",")[1],"base64");
```

Here's a listing  with a complete demo in and out:

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema,
      fs = require('fs');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var albumSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: Buffer
})

const Album = mongoose.model('Albumn', albumSchema);


async.series(
  [
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) => fs.readFile('./burger.png', callback),

          (data,callback) => {
            // Convert to Base64 and print out a bit to show it's a string
            let base64 = data.toString('base64');
            console.log(base64.substr(0,200));

            // Feed out string to a buffer and then put it in the database
            let burger = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');
            Album.create({
              "title": "burger",
              "image": burger
            },callback)
          },

          // Get from the database
          (album,callback) => Album.findOne().exec(callback),

          // Show the data record and write out to a new file.
          (album, callback) => {
            console.log(album);
            fs.writeFile('./output.png', album.image, callback)
          }

        ],
        callback
      )


  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
)
```

> **NOTE** The example was originally given with [asyncJS](https://caolan.github.io/async/) and older mongoose API, which notably has different connection options as shown in more modern and current API examples. Refer to these instead for testing on current NodeJS LTS releases:

Or with a a bit more modern syntax and API usage for comparison:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const albumSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: Buffer
});

const Album = mongoose.model('Album', albumSchema);

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )

    let data = await fs.readFile('./burger.png');

    // Convert to Base64 and print out a bit to show it's a string
    let base64 = data.toString('base64');
    console.log(base64.substr(0,200));

    // Feed out string to a buffer and then put it in the database
    let burger = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');
    await Album.create({ "title": "burger", "image": burger });

    // Get from the database
    // - for demo, we could have just used the return from the create() instead
    let album =  Album.findOne();

    // Show the data record and write out to a new file.
    console.log(album);
    await fs.writeFile('./output.png', album.image)


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

And even with "plain promises" where that is either preferred or you are still using a NodeJS without `async/await` support. But you [really should not be, considering v6.x reaches end of life in April 2019](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule):

```
// comments stripped - refer above
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const albumSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: Buffer
});

mongoose.connect(uri, opts)
  .then(conn =>
    Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )
  )
  .then(() => fs.readFile('./burger.png'))
  .then(data => {
    let base64 = data.toString('base64');
    console.log(base64.substr(0,200));
    let burger = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');
    return Album.create({ "title": "burger", "image": burger });
  })
  .then(() => Album.findOne() )
  .then(album => {
    console.log(album);
    return fs.writeFile('./output.png', album.image)
  })
  .catch(console.error)
  .then(() => mongoose.disconnect());
```

And here's a **burger.png** to play with:

[image]

> Also kudos to [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/2313887) which allows the sample image here to not appear as "huge" as it originally was, and yet still download at full size.