# What are some ways of storing images when using MongoDB Express React and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image, express

I am currently working on a project that has a Shoe model, as of right now I am only populating the image of the shoe with a imgUrl, but I would like to store images if possible. I know that I could use MongoDB and GridFS but from what I've read many say that MongoDB really isn't meant for storing large files. What would be recommended then? and how could I implement it in my MERN application?

Comment: you can try saving the image as base64 into MongoDB, but you may want to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869479/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-store-an-image-with-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is not a good place for storing files. If you want to store files, you should use storages like Amazon S3 or Google Could Storage.

The good practice is to store the files in a storage and then to just save the URL of the uploaded image in the MongoDB.

When it comes to Node.js and Express, I would suggest [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package middleware, which is primarily used for uploading files. If you would use Amazon S3 for a storage, there is also a plug-in [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) package that can be helpful.

You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY) on how to configure Multer and implement image upload on your Node.js server. Once the image is uploaded, Multer will return data to you with `destination` field included. You can then save that `destination` in the MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for.